How do I solve audience (aud) invalid claim error for downstream api service?
Anyone have a luck in providing aud token different from the domain name of the api endpoint? My Blazor calls the asp.net app (api) and got the error:

It worked totally fine when I had api app Application id and Jwt's "aud" in a form of api://[GUID]/write.access
After I updated it to the domain name (need custom claims, which won't work without it) it stopped working throwing the error.
Where I updated the audience in Entra:

Application Id URI of the api app on Expose Api page


Downstream Api config of my Blazor app



I guess that should be enough. The only possible root cause that I have in mind is different domain names: api endpoint is https://someappname.azurewebsites.net/accounts, and from you can see on the screenshots attached it's different

I think you're talking about authority. Yes, it's the same domain: "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/ymichuringmail.onmicrosoft.com". The ms Idp returns 2 tokens, identity_token and access_token with that aud (as in the error) inside

In my humble opinion, the web api is secured by Azure AD so that Azure AD will help to validate the access token from the incoming request header. In the API project's appsettings.json file, it will ask us to provide a scope so that we could use attribute like [RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")] before the Controller or action method. Therefore, if I set "Scopes": "Tiny.Greet" in appsetting, it will reconginze the default scope with api://client_id/Tiny.Greet, here the client id is what  we set in ClientId in appsettings. If we need to use different audie

nce, we shall need to add "Audience": "your_required_audience". Could you pls help test it? I don't have a custom domain for test.

If "Audience" doesn't work, could you pls try to set the Scopes as "Scopes": "https://ymichuringmail.xxxxx/write.access"?

adding "Audience": "https://ymichuringmail.onmicrosoft.com" to the AzureAd section of appSettings.json in Api app helped! api call passed. This section read by Microsoft.Identity.Web.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi. No other additional changes were made. Thank you!

You can set the expected aud claim value in JwtBearer like this:
        .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
        {
            opt.Authority = _configuration["openid:authority"];
            opt.Audience = "paymentapi";
            ...

this should be what the API should expect to see in the received access token.
I did write a blog post about this here: Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core

I use Masl lib for downstream calls, and it uses Saml schema for api calls, not Jwt. Nevertheless, the idea is the same: setting Audience explicitly, and it helped as per comments to the original post. So I'm marking it as a solution. Thanks

In my humble opinion, the web api is secured by Azure AD so that Azure AD will help to validate the access token from the incoming request header. In the API project's appsettings.json file, it will ask us to provide a scope so that we could use attribute like [RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")] before the Controller or action method.
Therefore, if I set "Scopes": "Tiny.Greet" in appsetting, it will reconginze the default scope with api://client_id/Tiny.Greet, here the client id is what we set in ClientId in appsettings. If we need to use different audience, we shall need to add "Audience": "your_required_audience" in appsettings.json.
Then thank you for your confirmation "Audience": "https://ymichuringmail.onmicrosoft.com" is the solution.
